# How do we turn PTFE powder into a paste we can dilute in a solvent

Tags: solutions

We want to create a binder we can use in our filter elements that is PTFE based, so we need to somehow create a paste, we can thin down with a solvent that will still hold the PTFE in suspension, long enough to dip our virgin glass microfibre elements in and get an even distribution through the element structure.
So far we have tried a DMP and DIBK mix to make a paste, and then diluted in MEK but we cannot get the PTFE to remain in suspension long enough.

Comment: Why not using available PTFE paste?

Answer (score 1):

You might try making a solution, rather than suspension. PTFE is *very* resistant to most solvents, but can form a [3% solution in perfluorinated hydrocarbon solvents](https://www.quora.com/Are-there-any-solvents-to-dissolve-teflon-or-PTFE) and, if I remember correctly (I could not find it on the web), in $\ce{Na}$ dissolved in liquid $\ce{NH3}$.

Comment: liquid NH4 or liquid NH3?

Comment: The cited [paper](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ma00081a008) applies only to high pressures and they used low MW PTFE that is much shorter than commercially-available PTFE. Normal PTFE is not appreciably soluble at normal temperatures and pressures in any known solvent.

Comment: Thanks, @Dissenter, for the correction. BTW, does someone know how Teflon is applied to cookware? Is it using Na in ammonia?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility that may work is to use an aqueous suspension of PTFE particles.
This is a common technique for dip-, spray-, and spin-coating all kinds of substrates.
There are a number of commercially available products containing PTFE particles stabilized by nonionic surfactants in water, such as this [one](https://chemours.com/Teflon_Industrial/en_US/products/product_by_name/teflon_ptfe/aqueous.html) from Chemours.

Another thing that may work depending on your application (namely, if your application requires only a thin film of a hydrophobic coating and not specifically PTFE particles), is the use of an amorphous fluoropolymer.
Most of these are copolymers of PTFE with a component that renders the polymer soluble in perfluorinated solvents (Cytop is a little different).
They are quite expensive, but can be used to make very uniform coatings again by dip, spray, spin and other coating methods with a polymer solution in a perfluorinated solvent, which is then removed by baking.
The big brands I am aware of are Chemours [Teflon AF](https://chemours.com/Teflon_Industrial/en_US/products/product_by_name/teflon_af/index.html), Cytonix [Fluoropel](http://fustf.wzhsp.servertrust.com/category-s/1844.htm), and AGC [Cytop](http://www.agcce.com/cytop/)

Comment: Hi, yes we have tried them but the problem is these solutions only coat the inner and outer layers of the filter creating a skin, even when diluted right down, and we couldn't find anyway to make them permeate the filter structure to make an actual binder.